# Drop down list using arrays excel vba

Tags: arrays, vba, excel

I'm trying to use a cell to select different data (from data validation and choosing list). The data in the list is from a data base filtered out.

I'm trying to take the data from the data base and put it into an array and then use that array to populate the list.

Not sure why this isn't working so any help is appreciated.

```
Sub filters()

Dim find As String
Dim array1(50)
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As String

Worksheets("Email Address").Select

find = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2").Value
For i = 2 To 400
k = Worksheets("Email Address").Cells(i, 1)
If k = find Then
    array1(j) = Worksheets("Email Address").Cells(i, 2)

Else

End If
Next i

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("G10").Select
    With Selection.Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:= _
        array1
        .IgnoreBlank = True
        .InCellDropdown = True
        .InputTitle = ""
        .ErrorTitle = ""
        .InputMessage = ""
        .ErrorMessage = ""
        .ShowInput = True
        .ShowError = True
    End With
    Range("G10").Select

End Sub
```

Comment: Not sure how much difference it will make, but try adding ".Value" to the cell references -- `Worksheets("Email Address").Cells(i, 1).Value` and `Worksheets("Email Address").Cells(i, 2).Value`

Comment: "isn't working" is not a description of a problem

Comment: Simple `Formula1:=Join(array1,",")` should do the trick...

Comment: @DirkReichel Would not he get a drop down list with one item which is one big string? I think I've encountered something like this before.

Comment: @AntiDrondert nope... `xlValidateList` uses comma separated list. it also ignores empty parts... but haven't seen the answer from wedge as he says exactly that (which is making my comment obsolete)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you can set an array as the list for data validation. I think it wants a comma separated string. You can just use the Join function to combine your array into a comma seperated string like

```
Join(array1, ",")
```

Also it doesn't look like your loop is setting up the array properly, as "j" is never defined or adjusted, so it is probably just setting the 0 element of the array over and over. Join will include empty array elements, so we would want the array to be sized to exactly what we need as well. You can define the array without a size like:

```
Dim array1() as String
```

And then in the loop resize the array as necessary:

```
j = 0
For i = 2 To 400
k = Worksheets("Email Address").Cells(i, 1)
If k = find Then
    ReDim Preserve array1(j)
    array1(j) = Worksheets("Email Address").Cells(i, 2)
    j = j + 1
End If
Next i
```

Comment: Good answer +1... still there is no real need for resizing as empty parts will be ignored `,,,1,,,,,2,,,,,3,,,,6,,,1,,,` still shows only `1,2,3,6,1` as possible selections without black rows in the dropdown list (but it looks much better doing it your way) ;)

Comment: not working for me, as few values in my array have comma in them, so join function is dividing value containing comma to two values.

Answer (score 1):

As explained in the accepted answer, 
Validation.Formula1 property does not accept array directly and join function is the solution

However, `Join(array1, ",")` does not work in the case when the count of characters in the resulting comma separated string exceeds 255 characters in which case ***"Application-defined or Object-defined error"*** is issued.

In fact the limit for a data validation drop down list is as below:

1. Shows up to 32,767 items if created using a named range (from a list
   on the worksheet)
2. Shows as many items as present in a comma delimited string provided
   the length of the string does not exceed 255 characters, including
   the separators.

The better solution to fill drop down list using arrays is to copy the array in a worksheet column and convert this copied range into a named range and use it in the `Formula1` property.

```vb
Dim rangeToCopyTo As Range
Set rangeToCopyTo = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A" & UBound(array1)) 
rangeToCopyTo = Application.Transpose(array1)
Names.Add "List1", rangeToCopyTo

Worksheets("Sheet1").Select
Range("G10").Select
With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="=List1"
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
Range("G10").Select
```

Answer (score 0):

Also keep in mind that - based on the Office you are working on - the separator does not have to be a comma, it can also be semicolon. If you want to be flexible on that, use this:

```
Formula1:=Join(array1, Excel.Application.International(xlListSeparator))
```

VBA will automatically change the separator for you.